# Mending broken text in a image for ocr

Tags: javascript, c#, python, opencv, imagemagick

I want this [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdUPE.png)

converted into this 
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhnyy.png)

I have tried edge detection in both Imagemagick and Opencv, but the results were not satisfactory. Is there any other method that could be used that is applicable for my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick, try morphology open with a custom 1D kernel.

```
convert fdUPE.png -morphology open "1x3: 1,0,1" result.png
```

[image]